# Reset listbox rowsource

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have my rowsource set through the properties window in access

In vba I tried using this to clear the content of the listbox:

```
me.list1.rowsource = ""
```

Ive decided to remove this code, but since my list box is empty, there rowsource in the properties is still populated.

Do I need to reset the rowsource or something? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: The rowsource set in the property window will persist unless you save the form with it empty. Setting it in VBA will not store it on the forms properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rowsource set in the property window will persist unless you save the form with it empty.

Setting it in VBA code will not store it on the forms properties.